# jquery cycle2 get width of current slide

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle2

I am using jQuery Cycle2 plugin http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/basic.php

I need to grab the width of the current slide/image and then use that to set the width of another element.

Each image may be a different width and I need a bar on top of the image to resize accordingly.

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow">
<img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/p1.jpg">
<img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/p2.jpg">
<img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/p3.jpg">
<img src="http://malsup.github.com/images/p4.jpg">
</div>
```

how can I get the width of the current/active slide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the hint that this plugin will add class `active` to current active image. So you can do like this to get your desired width:

```
var imgWidth = $(".cycle-slideshow").find("img.active").width();
```

then you can use this width value to set width for other element:

```
$("other element selector").width(imgWidth);
```

---

**Edit**

I assume HTML for your `next` and `prev` button look like this:

```
<div class="center">
    <a href="#" id="prev">Prev</a>
    <a href="#" id="next">Next</a>
</div>
```

Then you just need to do:

```
$("#prev, #next").on('click', function() {
    var imgWidth = $('.cycle-slideshow').find(".cycle-slide-active").width();
    $(".topbar").width(imgWidth); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  I thought that would do it, but the width of the 'other element' is not being updated when I click the next arrow for a new image.  I guess it's setting the width of the element based on the first active slide only?

Comment: @gteh then I'd suggest you to put above code inside the function where you handle click event of next arrow to make it updated.

Comment: Do you think you can help with that?  I am still learning jquery.  The API for cycle2 is here http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle2/api/  I assume I would do something like `$('.cycle-slideshow').on('cycle-after', function (e, opts, API) {
   var imgWidth = $($this).find(".cycle-slide-active").width();
   jQuery(".topbar").width(imgWidth);
  });` but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I am using #prev and #next, and tried your updated code :)  doesn't seem to work either.  this is driving me insane

Comment: @gteh I also don't know why. If you can create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), I'll try to help.

Comment: Got it!!  Your updated code was correct but $(this) needed to be change to $(".cycle-slideshow")    thank you!

Comment: @gteh You're correct, my bad :) I'm really appreciate if you can mark my answer as accepted.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29485/discussion-between-gteh-and-eli)